# Removing "False"-condition scales::dollar labels on ifelse within geom_label

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

trying to establish individual bar data labels ONLY if the value is negative. I was able to do it fine for a variable that comprised simple integers, but for a variable that needs to be formatted as dollar with the thousands separator, I can't seem to get rid of the "NA" label.

```
DolSumPlot <- ggplot(data = DolSums, aes(x = Group.1, fill = Group.2)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(weight = x), position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  labs(title = "Dollars Billed by Technician and Shop, Between 02/01/2018 and 05/31/2018", 
       y = "Dollars Billed", x = "Technician", fill = "Shop") + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits= c(NA,NA),
                     labels = scales::dollar,
                     breaks = seq(0, 50000 + 10000, 5000*2),
                     minor_breaks = seq(0,50000 + 10000, by = 5000)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") + 
  geom_label(aes(label=scales::dollar(ifelse(DolSums$x < 0, DolSums$x,NA)), 
                 y = DolSums$x), 
             show.legend = FALSE, size = 2.6, colour = "white", fontface = "bold")
```

**Data:**

```
DolSums = structure(list(Group.1 = c((names)), Group.2 = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Radio", 
"Video", "Engineering", "800Mhz", "PSSRP", "Other"), class = "factor"), 
    x = c(4646, 16008.5, 48793.1, 4040, 14468.25, 13332, 1565.5, 
    6060, 6549.85, 2929, 4444, 3257.25, 5904, 2029.5, 3321, 6767, 
    8105.25, 8105.25, 8130.5, 3131, 5075.25, 3383.5, 4418.75, 
    23381.5, 1363.5, -2323, 29133.45, 2550.25, 505, 26042.85, 
    35203.55, 35940.85, 1641.25, 45066.2, 37541.7, 606, 45439.9
    )), .Names = c("Group.1", "Group.2", "x"), row.names = c(NA, 
-37L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using the `data` argument in `geom_label` and subsetting only rows with negative `x`. Also note that since you already have `DolSums` as input, there is no need to write `DolSums$x`. Instead, use column name to refer to a specific column directly:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = DolSums, aes(x = Group.1, fill = Group.2)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(weight = x), position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  labs(title = "Dollars Billed by Technician and Shop, Between 02/01/2018 and 05/31/2018", 
       y = "Dollars Billed", x = "Technician", fill = "Shop") + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits= c(NA,NA),
                     labels = scales::dollar,
                     breaks = seq(0, 50000 + 10000, 5000*2),
                     minor_breaks = seq(0,50000 + 10000, by = 5000)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") + 
  geom_label(data = DolSums[DolSums$x < 0,], 
             aes(label=scales::dollar(x), 
                 y = x), 
             show.legend = FALSE, size = 2.6, colour = "white", fontface = "bold")
```

Comment: Hey, that's a neat trick! I didn't realize you could essentially set up a different dataset just to generate labels, that doesn't conflict with the main data. You've been quite the help, thank you.

Comment: @MarkBunster quite neat indeed. In fact, almost all `geom` functions in `ggplot2` has a data argument which allows you to input whatever dataset you need for that particular geom. You just need to check the documentation to make sure.

Comment: And to think the main genius behind all this works just down the road from me...thx again.